# How to use a list to slice another one then compute the average of each new list?

Tags: python

Imagine you have 2 lists (this is just an example the lists can have any values):

```
datapoints = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)]
classifications = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I want to use the list `classifications` to slice `datapoints` per cluster:

```
datapoints_0 = [(1, 1)]
datapoints_1 = [(2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)]
```

to be able finally to compute a new centroid per cluster:

```
centr = [(1, 1), (3.5, 3.5)]
```

Comment: What have you tried an where are you stuck? First thing that comes to mind: Iterate both lists together (`zip()`), and according to the index from `classifications` put the tuple from `datapoints` in a matching "bucket"

Comment: Hint: `clustered_points = {0: [(1, 1)], 1: [(2, 2), ...]}`, and just use the value in `classifications` as keys to that dict…

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data points by using list comprehension with zip function as:

```
datapoints_1=[x for x, y in zip(datapoints, classifications) if y==1]
```

Then to get the centroids, you can get the x_coordinate of datapoints_1 as:

```
centroid_1_x=sum([x[0] for x in datapoints_1])/len(datapoints_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a general solution for any number of unique values in classifications

```
from numpy import sum
datapoints = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)]
classifications = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1] 
d={}
for i,k in enumerate(classifications):
  if k not in d:
    d[k]=[]
  d[k].append(datapoints[i])
centr =[]
for k in d.keys():
  centr.append(tuple(sum(d[k],axis=0)/len(d[k])))
print(centr)
```

output:

```
[(1.0, 1.0), (3.5, 3.5)]
```

Comment: I've got an error : TypeError: sum() takes no keyword arguments
in the line : 11     centr.append(tuple(sum(d[k],axis=0)/len(d[k]))) do you know how to fix this

Comment: I replaced it with the following and it worked : /n
for k in d.keys():
    centr.append([sum(y) / len(y) for y in zip(*d[k])])

Comment: you should use the function sum() from numpy i forgot to import it .
it will work now .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

datapoints = np.array([(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)])
classifications = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1])

results = {i: np.mean(datapoints[classifications==i], axis=0) for i in set(classifications)}
# {0: array([1., 1.]), 1: array([3.5, 3.5])}
```

This saves you rolling your own mean function.